# When to use the "me" object in access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access VBA we can use  `Me.ControlName` to refer to a control name. When reading other people's VBA code I have realized that some people do not use the me keyword and simply use `ControlName` to refer to a control name.

Is one more efficient than the other? For me `Me.ControlName` is more readable but I am not sure what other people's opinion is.

Comment: Efficient as in faster? I doubt there's any noticeable difference. From my perspective, `Me` provides some level of self-documentation - you can see straight away that the identifier is something in the class (form) rather than a standalone variable

Comment: *For me Me.ControlName is more readable* Well, is exactl as you said. For you is more readable that way, but it could be that for other people is more readable the other way. Actually, I think this question is just opinion based, not a real coding problem.

Comment: `Me` solves real coding problems. See my answer below. The larger and more complex your Access application is, the more  you will need `Me`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several cases when you need to use `Me`:

1. When there are conflicting names:

   ```
   Dim someControl As Access.Control
   Set someControl = Me.SomeControl
   ```

   Obviously, this example is contrived, but there are real cases where conflicting names are logical
2. When you need to refer to the form object itself:

   In an external module:

   ```
   Public Sub DoStuffWithForm(someForm As Access.Form)
       'Does stuff with form
   End Sub
   ```

   In the form module:

   ```
   DoStuffWithForm Me
   ```

`Me` is just a general VBA concept. All class modules (and by extension, form modules) use the `Me` keyword to refer to themselves, but don't need to do that to refer to public properties. It's in a way similar to using `Application.Something`, you also don't need to do that, but it increases clarity when you do. And only in specific (rare) cases it's required.

Answer (score 3):

In VB, `Me` is the internal reference to the public interface of a class.

Things that can be referenced by `Me` in a class:

- Public properties, subs and functions
- Controls in Access form and report classes

Things that *cannot* be referenced:

- Private members of a class, including variables, properties, subs and functions

There are three uses of `Me`:

1. Provide a self-reference when calling functions or subs
2. Call the right method in case of duplicate names
3. In the IDE, typing `Me.` to more quickly select controls -- Thanks to Vlado for that suggestion!

**Example:**

- If there is a `Public Foo()` defined in a standard module and a `Public Foo()` in a class, `Me.Foo` will always call the class method, and plain `Foo` will do the same.
- However, if you delete or rename the class's `Foo()` method, `Me.Foo` will throw an error, *but* all plain `Foo` references will now call the global `Foo()` function instead!

As a programmer, I certainly *don't* want code that magically starts calling a different routine without warning if I edit a class module!

This is the best argument for always using `Me` to reference public members within class code.

Answer (score 2):

I use `Me.ControlName` just to make sure when I type that the control is on the form and I do not misspell it. It will appear in intellisense so I could confirm it by pressing TAB.

Comment: That is a nice side benefit of using Me in the IDE. You get both increased accuracy and speed with this trick.