# VBA Excel - conditional-based shape movement doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I have several shapes, which must be placed at certain locations on the worksheet depending on the conditions.
I've prepared the case statement, which doesn't work, unfortunately.
My code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim Client      As String
    Client = ActiveSheet.Range("N4").Value
    
    Dim CFShape     As Shape, NetShape As Shape, VMShape As Shape
    Dim SP          As Object
    
    Set CFShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("CFajbr")
    Set NetShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Netomy")
    Set VMShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Vadzyn")
    
    Select Case Client
        Case "CiFajbra"
            With CFShape
                .Top = 100
                .Left = 50
            End With
            For Each SP In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If SP.Name <> "CFajbr" Then
                    SP.Top = 200
                    SP.Left = 800
                End If
            Next
        Case "VadzynNB"
            With VMShape
                .Top = 100
                .Left = 50
            End With
            For Each SP In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If SP.Name <> "Vadzyn" Then
                    SP.Top = 200
                    SP.Left = 800
                End If
            Next
        Case "Netomic"
            With NetShape
                .Top = 100
                .Left = 50
            End With
            For Each SP In ActiveSheet.Shapes
                If SP.Name <> "Netomy" Then
                    SP.Top = 200
                    SP.Left = 800
                End If
            Next
    End Select
    
End Sub
```

When I pull one shape in a certain place I want another one back in some position.
I can't execute this code as nothing happens on my worksheet. Where the problem might be?

Comment: The `SelectionChange`-Routine is not triggered when you select (or move) a shape. It is triggered only if you select cells.

Comment: I select the cell and change the value from the dropdown. Nothing happens

Comment: Assuming that your dropdown is a data validation rule (and not a control): Use the `Change`-Trigger, not the `SelectionChange`

Comment: Btw you can use `Me` in a sheet code module to refer to the containing sheet.

Comment: What do you mean by Me?

Comment: The `Me` object has [special meaning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/me-keyword), it's very helpful when you to [know when to use it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54430012/4717755).